# Index by ascending date but have past dates displayed last

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I want to query rows by day in this order:

1. today
2. future
3. past

Currently I'm doing a simple query like this:

```
getLatest(howMany, offset) {
    return knex
        .select('*')
        .from('event')
        .orderBy('start_time', 'asc')
        .offset(offset)
        .limit(howMany);
}
```

But the problem with that is it shows past timestamps first. I know I can get past records like this:

```
knex('event')
    .select('id')
    .whereRaw("start_time < NOW()")
```

UPDATE: Is there a way to make this work with the offset? This query will be ran for an endless feed every time when users reach the bottom to fetch more events. Indexing maybe?

This is my schema:

```
knex.schema.createTable('event', (table) => {
    table.increments().primary();
    table.dateTime('start_time').notNullable();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use [`orderByRaw`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-orderByRaw) to create an `ORDER BY` clause like

```
ORDER BY start_time < current_timestamp, start_time
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with the offset? This query will be ran for an endless feed when users reach the bottom to fetch more events. I get a feeling this would require some sort of indexing but I've never used indexes before.

Comment: @VladyVeselinov There is a special chapter in every optimization book for limit/offset. Here is one good [slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/p2d2-pagination-done-the-postgresql-way) on this topic.
But for me, I feel like this is like "upper" advanced level. For small projects (below gigabytes/terrabytes of data) – limit/offset works just fine.
Also, there is a `current_date` in postgres. `current_timestamp` returns current time, while `current_date` – start of the day.

Comment: I agree with most of what @coockoo wrote, except that I think that indexes and keyset pagination are something that every developer should understand. Since this query is only over a single table and the database is PostgreSQL, you should give it a try. The only difficulty would be the expression `start_time < current_timestamp`, which is not indexable. So maybe it would be best to compose the list from two separate queries, one for future and one for past entries. Or, if the table is small (but only then), go with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.